# Did Hemingway beat drunks with a club at a bar in Key West?

Tags: united-states

According to [some guy on reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/pics/comments/2lqzn6/club_that_ernest_hemingway_used_to_use_to_beat/), Hemingway used to beat drunks with a club in a bar in Key West. Supposedly the club is exhibited in that bar and still has blood on it.

[image: Hemingway's supposed drunk-beating club]

Did he?

And if he did, was that club the one he used?

Comment: An interesting link, although it doesn't provide an answer: http://www.openculture.com/2015/11/james-joyce-picked-drunken-fights-then-hid-behind-ernest-hemingway.html